# Kafka Connect Sink "Passthrough" Connector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Does the kafka jdbc sink connector support writing what it consumes to a different topic.  I am looking for a passthrough mechanism and illustrated below.  If it does not, I could chain a sink and the source (reading from where the sink wrote) but do not think that will be as performant.  Perhaps I could modify the existing sink connector to accomplish this?

```
Topic 1 -> Sink Connector ->  Topic 2
               |
               V
               DB
```

Answer (score 0):

The Connect Framework allows writing to a Dead-Letter Queue topic for error-causing records, but there is no such `tee`-like feature in Connect.

If you want a source reading from what a sink wrote, then you would have two connectors.

For example,

```
JDBC_Sink -> DB -> Debezium -> Topic
```

Comment: Why Debezium over the JDBC Source Connector?

Comment: CDC captures all the changes. It was only an example

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to write a simple Kafka Streams application that forwards everything from topic 1 to topic 2. And use the connector as is to sink contents from topic 1 into the DB.